# Performing an action when a user decides to stay after onbeforeunload event

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval, onbeforeunload

Here's my problem...

I want to preform an action once the user decides to stay.
Since I don't have a direct way of doing so, I wanted to use the setTimeout and setInterval  as following:

I'm using a setInterval to check the page every seconds, and if the isOnBeforeUnload var is true, it means the user triggered the onbeforeunload event by tying to leave.

What I want to happen is counting to 1 second, assuming after a second if the page is not unloaded yet - the user stayed.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
                isOnBeforeUnload = true;
                return "You have an unsaved update!";
            };

window.timeout = setInterval(function() {

      if (isOnBeforeUnload) {
      var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(doClick, 1000);
      isOnBeforeUnload = false;
      }
   }, 1000);

function doClick() {
      //do some actions... 
      }
```

This code works fine on Chrome and IE, but not on FF... Can someone please help? I need it to work on IE9,10,11, Chrome and FF.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simpler solution:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('Stayed');
    // The user stayed, so do whatever you want
  }, 100);
  return 'Dont go!';
};
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/mejugile/1/edit). It works in FF and Chrome. I can't test in IE, though.

Comment: @jsLover Works then as well for me in Chrome and FF. Which browser version are you trying?

Comment: @SomeGuy I'm using FF 30.0. I had a very similar code to what you offered that came back from QA and I was told that navigating by typing a URL or using the home button/favorite buttons and choosing to LEAVE is not navigating away but preforming the actions...

Comment: @jsLover I don't get it. Do you want it to not be triggered if they navigate away by typing a URL?

Comment: @SomeGuy the flow should be: If the user stays, I should call function doClick(). If he chooses to leave, I want to let him leave. Using the suggested code is not letting the user leave in case he types a URL/Clicks on the home button/ Clicks on favorites.

Comment: So if the user types a URL, you don't want the confirmation box to show at all?

Comment: @SomeGuy If the user types a URL I want the "Dont go!" box to show up, but if he chooses to LEAVE, I don't want to trigger  doClick() function.

Comment: That is how it is. Code can't run on a page if it isn't open!

Comment: @SomeGuy When you run the code you suggested, the user get's the Don't Go!, and after he chooses to leave, the page is acting as if he chose to stay - the doClick() function is triggered.

Comment: @SomeGuy I'm not sure I'm explaining myself properly. I'll try again, if you may... The user really wants to leave. He gets this alert/confirmation box asking him to stay. But he wants to leave anyway. So he's got 2 options: stay and leave the page. The "leave" option should take him to the URL he typed!! only in case he stays I want to trigger the doClick() function. But he chose "leave". this code is not letting him leave.